# Is there any negative side-effects to switching between multiple TFS servers?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional, with TFS hosted on a server for work, and TFS hosted on TFS preview for personal projects.

I have noticed that I can add both using the **Connect to Team Foundation Server** dialogue box in Visual Studio, and I can switch between them by selecting the server I want to work from the dropdown box and clicking **Connect**.

Everything appears to be working ok, but I have two questions:

1. Is this advisable?
2. Could there be any negative side-effects to switching between multiple TFS servers on one computer/Visual Studio install?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no issues with this setup. I have about 6 of 'm. Different clients use their own TFS servers, the Team Foundation Service for personal projects and a few Microsoft Collaborative projects. Codeplex also provides a TFS interface for sourcecontrol.

Only downside I can think of, is that one must remember where a project is residing.

Comment: OK thanks, I've heard TFS can be buggy and didn't want to mess anything up!

Comment: TFS generally isn't buggy at all. Some people just don't know how to use it, or want to use it in unintended ways. Should you have more specific concerns, then please put them in a new question.